# pandas plot function gives ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe object, df as follows:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 4460 entries, 2013-04-02 00:24:14.655000 to 2013-05-01 08:05:37.820000
Columns: 3928 entries, 0.36813255,37.5913675 to 9.99963814285,76.3137843191
dtypes: float64(3928)
```

df.plot() gives me

```
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension
```

There as no NaN values in the dataframe. Strangely, certain ranges of the dataframe does plot well. For example the following works:

```
df.ix[:,:3].plot()
```

Any idea what could be happening??

**EDIT:**

Sample data:

```
lat_lng                     0.36813255,37.5913675  1.33731422941,103.965656679
date                                                                          
2013-04-02 00:24:14.655000                      0                            0
2013-04-02 08:05:39.719000                      0                            1
2013-04-02 08:16:56.986000                      0                            0
2013-04-02 08:18:00.408000                      0                            0
2013-04-02 08:18:38.530000                      10                           0
2013-04-02 08:24:02.663000                      0                            0
2013-04-02 08:24:27.286000                      0                            0
2013-04-02 08:24:46.466000                      0                            1
2013-04-02 08:25:32.366000                      0                            0
2013-04-02 08:25:52.018000                      0                            0
```

This wouldn't plot:

```
lat_lng                     0.36813255,37.5913675  1.33731422941,103.965656679  1.36110856929,103.886645147  10.0001097537,76.3023939556
date                                                                                                                                    
2013-04-02 00:24:14.655000                      0                            0                            0                            0
2013-04-02 08:05:39.719000                      0                            0                            0                            0
2013-04-02 08:16:56.986000                      0                            0                            0                            0
2013-04-02 08:18:00.408000                      0                            0                            0                            0
2013-04-02 08:18:38.530000                      0                            0                            0                            0
2013-04-02 08:24:02.663000                      0                            0                            0                            0
2013-04-02 08:24:27.286000                      0                            0                            0                            0
2013-04-02 08:24:46.466000                      0                            0                            0                            0
2013-04-02 08:25:32.366000                      0                            0                            0                            0
2013-04-02 08:25:52.018000                      0                            0                            0                            0
```

Comment: Can you post the data itself? What is your pandas and matplotlib version?

Comment: The values are numbers between 0 and 100. The Pandas version is 0.11.0 ans matplotlib is 1.2.1.

Comment: This sample data plots fine, though I expect the entire dataset with 4000 long_lats each each with 4500 datetimes would look a mess and almost certainly not be useful...

Comment: Same here, no issue with the sample data. To be sure i reverted to pandas version 0.11.0, my matplotlib version is 1.2.0. You mention there are no NaN in the DataFrame, but the index is 4460 entries and columns 3928 (missing values are not counted)

Comment: I had used the fillna(0) to remove NaN. The the data i have is supposed to have 4460 enties. I cannot estimate the number of cols though. The sample data was  df.ix[:10,0:2] which plots well. But as soon as I change the indicies to say something like,  df.ix[:10,0:10] it does not plot.

Comment: Can you show a slice of the data, that does not plot?

Comment: @WouterOvermeire OP has updated, there is something fishy here...

Comment: yes, i get the same error now - strange. Interesting example, will look into this a bit more when i have some time.

Comment: Just gave this another spin on master to have a detailed look, works fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is *something* wrong with the column names (being too long?)... I can confirm your second example won't plot on 0.11.

This plots fine if you use a range:

```
df.columns = range(4)
```

and also plots fine if you use a MultiIndex / something more elaborate:

```
In [10]: pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(map(lambda X: [float(x) 
                                                  for x in X.split(',')],
                                        df.columns),
                                   names=['lat', 'long'])

Out[11]:
MultiIndex
[(0.36813255, 37.5913675), (1.33731422941, 103.965656679), (1.36110856929, 103.886645147), (10.0001097537, 76.3023939556)

In [12]: df1.columns = Out[11]

In [13]: df1
Out[13]:
lat                          0.368133    1.337314    1.361109    10.000110
long                        37.591367   103.965657  103.886645  76.302394
date
2013-04-02 00:24:14.655000           0           0           0           0
2013-04-02 08:05:39.719000           0           0           0           0
2013-04-02 08:16:56.986000           0           0           0           0
2013-04-02 08:18:00.408000           0           0           0           0
2013-04-02 08:18:38.530000           0           0           0           0
2013-04-02 08:24:02.663000           0           0           0           0
2013-04-02 08:24:27.286000           0           0           0           0
2013-04-02 08:24:46.466000           0           0           0           0
2013-04-02 08:25:32.366000           0           0           0           0
2013-04-02 08:25:52.018000           0           0           0           0
```

(this plots fine too.)

Comment: I have experimented with longer column names and it had worked fine.

Comment: @Nithin yeah, I don't think it can be that either, but it is definitely *something* to do with the column names (since when changing them it plots ok)...

Comment: Making it a multiindex, plotted all 4600 rows :)
I need to look more into multiIndex.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error msg and the reason was the the column name was a number and not a text!

Comment: The column name was explicitly converterd to a string using the str(). I am sure its not a number, in my case.

Comment: Just because you get the same error message doesn't necessarily mean you have the same problem.